# UITabBarItem Color can only be changed once?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to dynamically change the bottom tab text color depending on what event occurs.  The tab text color allows you to change it once but it wont work the second time around?

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

I need to change the tab bar text color multiple times but it doesn't let me.  I can only change it once?  The color stays the same the second time around when calling the code above

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use an "if loop", the code would look something like that:

```
if condition == "Whatever"{
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}else{
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
}
```

Notice that condition should be whatever you call: "what event occurs" and the text on "" should be replaced with whatever makes your event happen.

If I did help you, please give me positive points. Kind Regards!

Comment: Everytime a viewcontroller is changed I need to change the tabbaritem text color.  It changes on the initial load but never on any other clicks.   I checked the breakpoint and the code gets executed but the color never changes.  I think its a bug in xcode or ios?

Comment: your code above is an if statement to change the color.... I'm asking why the color doesnt change the second time around even though when i step through it my breakpoint executes the code

Comment: In that case I don´t see any issue with your code. I´m going to try to reproduce the issue as soon as I reach home.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out

```
self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color], forState: .Selected)
```